# Store a particular column values of a dataframe in comma separated format in a file in hdfs in scala

Tags: dataframe, list, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have dataframe which has only one column containing json data strings in it.The size of this dataframe is 50M.I want to store this json strings in comma separated array format in specified numbers of file in hdfs.

Expected output in files:
The output of file will look like below format.

[Json_string_1,Json_string_2,Json_string_3,Json_string_4,....Json_string_n-1,Json_string_n]

```scala
val ResultDf = Targetdf.repartition(numOfFiles).withColumn("id",lit(1))
ResultDf.groupBy("id").
  agg(collect_list("value").alias("value_array")).
  select("value_array").
  write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(HdfsPath)
```

Each file will contain 2M records like above array format that I mentioned in my post.

Getting below error while trying with above code.

23/05/11 07:43:09 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 3 on ncepnhpwrka0302.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000004 on host: ncepnhpwrka0302.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:09.149]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:09.149]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:09.150]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:11 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ncepnhpwrka0310.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000002 on host: ncepnhpwrka0310.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:11.016]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:11.016]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:11.016]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:13 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 7 on ncepnhpwrka0165.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000008 on host: ncepnhpwrka0165.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:13.064]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:13.065]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:13.075]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:14 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 9 on ncepnhpwrka0035.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000012 on host: ncepnhpwrka0035.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:14.757]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:14.757]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:14.757]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:16 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 8 on ncepnhpwrka0286.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000010 on host: ncepnhpwrka0286.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:16.701]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:16.702]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:16.702]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:21 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 5 on ncepnhpwrka0056.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000006 on host: ncepnhpwrka0056.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:21.067]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:21.068]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:21.068]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:22 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 6 on ncepnhpwrka0315.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000007 on host: ncepnhpwrka0315.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:22.203]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:22.216]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:22.216]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:27 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 4 on ncepnhpwrka0012.hadoop.charter.com: Container marked as failed: container_e544_1683576000275_46271_01_000005 on host: ncepnhpwrka0012.hadoop.charter.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-05-11 07:43:26.870]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-05-11 07:43:26.870]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
[2023-05-11 07:43:26.870]Killed by external signal

23/05/11 07:43:27 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2039)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:536)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch$.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala:134)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:536)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch$.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala:134)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2039)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
... 27 more
23/05/11 07:43:27 ERROR AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch$: ()
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:536)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch$.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala:134)
at com.charter.ec.hbase.AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.main(AccountRdeInitialLoadBatch.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2039)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
... 27 more

Dataframe value column is containing below format of json strings init's each row.

example json:

```json
{
    "accountBalance": [],
    "accountCloseDt": "2021-07-29",
    "accountCreateDt": "2021-01-02",
    "accountNumber": "8260160810392753",
    "accountOpenDt": "2021-01-02",
    "accountPaymentHist": "ZZZZZZZ0",
    "billingCustomerId": "1028446314",
    "connectDate": "2021-01-02",
    "creditBureauPin": "XMLJY0191565242",
    "delinquentStartDate": null,
    "disconnectReasonCd": "MO",
    "domainEntityMetadata": {
        "domainEntityName": "account_rde",
        "jsvCompatibility": [
            "1.0.0"
        ],
        "keyPath": [
            "fqAccountId"
        ],
        "messageTimestamp": "2023-04-25T17:37:14.876Z",
        "modifiedTimestamp": "2023-04-25T17:37:14.876Z",
        "sourceSystem": "SOLO Services/ENI Feed"
    },
    "ebppInd": "N",
    "electronicBillFlag": "N",
    "lastStatementDt": "2021-07-30",
    "lastStatementEndDt": "2023-03-28",
    "lastStatementStartDt": "2023-03-01",
    "lineOfBusinessDetail": [
        {
            "Status": "N",
            "Type": "I"
        }
    ],
    "paperlessBilling": "Y",
    "paymentMethodCd": null,
    "soloAccountId": "263297612",
    "spcDivisionId": "CTX.8260",
    "ucan": "16270315021"
}
```

Comment: I need this answer urgent . Please help me out.

Comment: Could you add more details? Like the code you have, the exception produce, an example of the json you have, etc

Comment: I have added the details. can you please check.

Comment: Can you please add the full error stack trace you're bouncing against? That will help us understand what your issue might be :)

Comment: Added the full error stack trace.

Comment: Please look into it I need the solution urgent.

Comment: any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The data of each partition resides in a single node machine and Spark will create a task for each partition.

All of that includes Shuffle operations and data will be moved to other partitions. So here we are talking about an expensive operation that depends on your numFiles value (partition number).
**PS: the number of partition to set is not randomly chosen.. you should be very careful about this choice. Also you have to get your cluster configurations ( memory, cores ect..)**

You said you have a 50M dataframe, so you can apply the transformations ( agg, groupBy..) before applying the repartition operation.

There is a work around for your use case, you can save the results on hdfs without modifying the partition value and then add a processing layer that will assure the small files creation depending on the size (2M per file)

Comment: I tried without repartition also but getting same exception.

Comment: for a first step, try to save the json results in a single file by doing a coalesce(1)

Comment: After storing what process I should use to store 2m data per file in array format. Any hints or suggestion..